# Correlating with Firebase and Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to compare the "email id" using Firebase authentication with the email field in all documents under the fixed collection in Firestore?

For eg : if a person is signing up with `xyz@gmail.com` using Firebase Auth and from admin Activity I am storing the user "email-id" as `xyz@gmail.com`.

If a user now logins, they click on their view my details button, can they be able to view the details?

I used whereEqualTo to compare but notihng happens
How to search the email field in all documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to compare the "email id" using Firebase authentication with the email field in all documents under the fixed collection in firestore?

Yes, it is. First you need to get the email address of the logged-in user from the authentication process like this:

```
String emailAddress = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

Assuming that your "fixed" collection looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- users (collection)
         |
         --- uid (document)
              |
              --- emailAddress: "xyz@gmail.com"
```

To comparate the email of the logged-in user with all the email addresses from the database, you need to use this query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("emailAddress", emailAddress);
```